# Заштрихованная область

Tags: python, c++, pascal, vba

Что писать в if? Я очень долго думал, но никак не могу придумать. Нужно определить входит ли точка с координатами (x, y) в закрашенную область.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Harry от трех?

Comment: На худой конец - лежит ли она с нужной стороны от пяти прямых...

Comment: "Я очень долго думал" - можно узнать, что Вы думали?

Comment: https://resh.edu.ru/subject/lesson/6122/conspect/

Answer (score 2):

Раз С++ разрешен...

```
if (y < 7 - x && y < 3 + x && y > 3 - 2*x && y > 2*x - 5 && y > 1)
```

Ну, или если на границе тоже можно считать как внутри - замените `>` на `>=` (ну, а `<` на `<=`)...

Можно - если есть функция `abs()` - короче:

```
if (y < 5 - abs(x-2) && y > 2*abs(x-2) - 1 && y > 1)
```